# Can someone explain the use of the transistor in this circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-communications

I came across a schematic which implemented a 1 Wire interface. However, this 1-Wire interface circuit also includes a transistor connected as shown in the picture. Can somebody expain why this has been done? I read on a Maxim AN about using transistors in order to be able to use a stronger pullup (R2) but I don't see how that works.
Thank you for your help[image]

Comment: Looks a bit like the circuit required for devices that need a lot of parasitic power, but the circuit in the schematic does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work.

The transistor is in a common-base configuration, which provides no current gain at all (actually very slightly less than unity). All of the current from the pullup must pass through the open-collector uC pin, along with the bias current flowing through R1.

The transistor simply functions as a one-way current gate. It's slightly better than an ordinary diode in the sense that its forward drop (V<sub>CE</sub>) when conducting is on the order of 200-300 mV, instead of the 600-700 mV of a diode. This helps with the noise margin on the one-wire bus.

A better configuration would be common-emitter, with the base resistor connected to the uC pin, but then the pin would have to be configured as totem-pole (drives high as well as low) and the polarity of the signal would have to be inverted — the bus is pulled low when the pin is high. In this configuration, you would be able to have a pullup that the uC couldn't handle directly.

An N-channel MOSFET would work even better with regard to the noise margin (in either circuit configuration).

Comment: I must respectfully disagree. I use that transistor arrangement often. Although I normally use that configuration for level-shifting, here it is being used as a diode with extremely-low forward drop. Think about it. The base bias ensures that the transistor is saturated when the uC pin is Low. The transistor is OFF when the uC pin is Hi.

Comment: @DwayneReid: With regard to your first comment, you're saying the same thing that I am -- there's no disagreement there. Take another look at my second paragraph. With regard to your second comment, no, this is definitely NOT common-emitter.

Comment: You said "It doesn't work".  I completely disagree - it actually works quite well.  As I mentioned in my previous comment, I do have experience with that circuit topology.

Comment: "It doesn't work" refers to the fact that it does not allow you to use a stronger pullup than what the uC pin could handle on its own anyway, because the circuit ONLY functions as a diode -- it has no current gain. It's a direct response to the OP's statement *"I don't see how that works."*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which app notes you were looking at but a good document for strong pull-ups would be Maxim's AN4206, gives you a decent set of options and a start at explaining the timing involved.

Note that the strong pull-up requires special timing as the 1-Wire bus communication is 'offline' during that phase.  This technique is used for (hopefully infrequent) EEPROM programming or other power hungry operations.

For an MCU circuit as above you'd use a PMOS (with gate pull-up to Vcc, gate controlled by MCU), that way you don't need charge pumps to turn on the FET.

Comment: yeah I agree, in the application notes they have the base connected to the micro not the VCC rail...